# Excel Add-In does not load in few machines

Tags: excel, office-js

We have built an Excel Add-In that allows users to bring in data from an external system, modify it in Excel tables and push it back to the external system. It requires access to the browser's session storage, local storage and Indexed db. This add in loads fine in most of the machines. But we have noticed that in few machines, it doesn't load on startup.

We tried various options to debug this but couldn't figure out the root cause.

Note that to check if its an issue with our Add-In, we tried to load the **Script Lab** Add-In. But even this Add-In was stuck at initial loading page and it never loaded.

Following are the Excel and IE versions of users who are facing this:

- Excel Version: 16.0.7726.1049 32-bit

  - IE Version: 11.0.9600.18763 Update Version: 11.0.45
- Excel Version: 16.0.7369.2188

  - IE Version: 11.0.1045.10586 Update Version: 11.0.45

We checked few settings in IE related to DOM storage, enabling "Allow Website caches and Databases" option etc..but it didn't help.

Is there something in IE settings or in Excel that we can look at to see what is causing it?

Comment: Could you explain what is meant by "doesn't load on startup"? Are you saying the Add-in fails with an error when you launch it or you're expecting it to automatically load when Excel launches?

Comment: Did you check `Trust Center` settings in Excel to see if they have `Disable all Applications Add-ins` marked?

Comment: @MarcLaFleur-MSFT  In case of Script Lab, Add-in is stuck at initial page( where 3 dots indicating the loading are shown). It never goes past that screen. In our case (an angular app) the initial view doesn't load. During the loading of initial view we do, among other things, access local storage and session storage.